# Save button with Ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm making an online form for customers and now adding a submit button which saves the record in database. Is there any way i can submit data using AJAX ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample jQuery code which may help:

```
$('.submitter').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    'url' : 'url.php',
    'type' : 'POST',
    'data' : $('.myForm').serialize(), //Gets all of the values from a form
    'success' : function(data) {
      if (data == 'saved') {
        alert('Form was saved!');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. If you don't mind can you tell me any website which can teach me how to implement JQUERY ?

Comment: Not a problem. jQuery is really just JavaScript. So if you are comfortable with that, then you will transition well into jQuery. jQuery's documentation site [http://docs.jquery.com ] and their API site [http://api.jquery.com ] are about the best documentation sites I've seen. lynda.com has a great course on it [http://www.lynda.com/jQuery-training-tutorials/246-0.html ], for a fee, and here is a great, free video series to get you kick-started [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/15-resources-to-get-you-started-with-jquery-from-scratch ].

Comment: Everything I learned about jQuery came from here [http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Cookbook-Animal-Guide-Lindley/dp/0596159773 ].

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery. It will do the job for you.

Comment: Is there any specific website for this functionality?

Comment: I have posted a sample of a jQuery snippet which may help.